# Javascript - issues with regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that should be validated to be in the form of something like `"Readdata.v5"`.  What I do in my code, is I split the string based on the `.` (I check to make sure there is exactly one `.` in the string, so all other cases are handled).  I want to validate it so that the first part of the string follows the format of a phrase, followed by any character to the period.  The second part should start with the char `v` and then be followed by any number.  This is the regex I have so far:

```
console.log("first field validation: " + splitArray[0].match(/^\"(Create|Read|Update|Delete)[a-zA-Z]*.$/));
console.log("Second field validation: " + splitArray[1].match(/^.vd+\"$/));
```

However, it doesn't seem like my regex is working.  Did I make a mistake?  The values in the array are correct, and split the values correctly (the quotations are a part of the string).

Comment: Digit pattern is `\d`, not `d`.

Comment: can't you do it with single regex. i don't understand need of splitting

Comment: @CodeManiac I suppose, regex is something I'm not the best at.

Comment: @user3334871 you can do it with single regex itself. well if you some more example i can write one.

Comment: When you split the data, then `.` character shouldn't be included in your regex.

Comment: @CodeManiac the string should be one of the listed phrases to start, followed by any letters if at all.  then a `.`, then v#.  It should all be included in quotes.  So another example would be "Createuser.v4" or could just be "Delete.v100"

Comment: @rv7 doesn't the `.` have a meaning in regex?  If I was using the literal `.` I would have to escape it?

Comment: I know that `.` denotes literal as well, but using `^.vd+\"$` regex, you can't match "v5\"" as it starts with `v`.

Comment: Use `var isValid = /^"(?:Create|Read|Update|Delete)[a-zA-Z]*\.v\d+"$/.test(s)` to validate the string in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use this**

```
^"(Create|Read|Update|Delete)[a-zA-Z]*\.v\d+"$
```

> Explanation

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `(Create|Read|Update|Delete)` - Will match `Create` or `Read` or `Update` or `Delete`.
- `[a-zA-Z]*` - Will match any character zero or more time.
- ``.`- will match`.`.
- `v\d+` - Will match `v` followed by one or more digits.
- `$` - End of string.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/N6NDNa/2/)

Comment: Shouldn't you include the quotes around `"Readdata.v5"`?

Comment: @rv7 i thought those were used just to string.

Comment: Actually, the quotes are a part of the string :) . I just put `^\"(Create|Read|Update|Delete)[a-zA-Z]*\.v\d+\"$`

Comment: @user3334871 my bad i thought that was just representation of string.updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate that there is a "." in the chain, you can do this:

```
var stringToValidate = 'jon.foo';

if(!!stringToValidate.indexOf('.')){
 console.log('true')
}
```

the conditional is evaluated a true or false